# formatting text in <h> tag to show text with space

Tags: css

I am trying to show message in `<h5>`

```
<h5>S  e  n  t  i  m  e  n  t       a  n  a  l  y  s  i  s</h5>
```

Codepan : [CODEPAN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/EvFsD)

css:

```
h5
{
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It should show space between each character and two space between word.
but it shows all character continuously without space.

Comment: You can even use `&nbsp;`

Comment: <h5>S e  n  t  i  m  e  n  t&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a  n  a  l  y  s  i  s</h5>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `letter-spacing` property.

HTML:

```
<h5>Sentiment analysis</h5>
```

CSS:

```
h5{
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    text-decoration:underline;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nwlqa)

Comment: thanks, i could not upvote bcoz of  < 15 score. Upvote my question if you like it

Answer (score 4):

Use the `white-space: pre` style to preserve white space.

```
h5
{
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    text-decoration:underline;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `letter-spacing` css rule

```
h5
{
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    text-decoration:underline;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdphI)

Comment: thanks, i could not upvote bcoz of  < 15 score. Upvote my question if you like it

Answer (score 1):

Change the html to normal word.

HTML

```
<h5>Sentiment analysis</h5>
```

CSS

```
 letter-spacing is for space between letter. And word-spacing is for space between word.

 h5
 {
      margin-left: 36%;
      color:#C0C0C0;
      text-decoration:underline;
      letter-spacing:4px;
      word-spacing : 5px;
 }
```

DEMO : http://cdpn.io/EvFsD

Comment: thanks, i could not upvote bcoz of  < 15 score. Upvote my question if you like it

Answer (score 1):

You must use the property `white-space`, specifically `pre-wrap`.

```
h5 {
    margin-left: 36%;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    text-decoration: underline;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IalEu)**

You can find more information about this property **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)**.

Comment: thanks, i could not upvote bcoz of  < 15 score. Upvote my question if you like it

Answer (score 1):

For spacing between letters use "letter-spacing"
and likewise for word spacing use "word-spacing"

```
h5{
letter-spacing : 3px;
word-spacing : 5px;
}
```

You can change the px value as per your requirement.